# How do I modify the coordinates of an object from a script?

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

I want it to be teleported to a place when it collides with an object and I already have the if the only thing I am missing is a command to modify the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find something like this in very nearly every Unity tutorial ever written, so please be sure to search for existing documentation and guides before asking here.

```
void MoveObjectTo(GameObject mover, Vector3 position) {
    mover.transform.position = position;
}
```